# MariaDBの起動に失敗する

Tags: mysql, centos

CentOS 7.1.1503にMariaDBをインストールし、`systemctl start mysql`をしましたが起動できませんでした。

こちらのサイトを参考に作業しました。

[CentOS 6.5にMariaDB 10.0.12をインストール(yumを使用)](https://blog.lovezawa.com/centos-65-mariadb-install-yum/)

```
# vim /etc/yum.repos.d/mariadb.repo
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0.20/centos7-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
```

> これで問題なければインストールは完了です。「Transaction Check Error:」とかが出たら、mysql-libsを削除すると良いそうな。

途中Transaction Check Error:が出てしまったのでmysql-libsは削除しました。

`systemctl start mysql`の結果は

```
# systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

`systemctl status mysql`とか`journalctl -xn`の結果は

```
# systemctl status mysql
mysql.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 水 2015-07-01 12:12:03 JST; 6min ago
  Process: 6341 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 7月 01 12:12:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
 7月 01 12:12:03 localhost.localdomain mysql[6341]: Starting MySQL. ERROR!
 7月 01 12:12:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 7月 01 12:12:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
 7月 01 12:12:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.


# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at 水 2015-07-01 01:58:42 JST, end at 水 2015-07-01 12:20:01 JST. --
 7月 01 12:17:12 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[597]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a00:27ff:fe51:68d4
 7月 01 12:19:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain mysql[6869]: Starting MySQL. ERROR!
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
-- Logs begin at 水 2015-07-01 01:58:42 JST, end at 水 2015-07-01 12:20:01 JST. --
 7月 01 12:17:12 localhost.localdomain avahi-daemon[597]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::a00:27ff:fe51:68d4
 7月 01 12:19:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain mysql[6869]: Starting MySQL. ERROR!
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start and stop MySQL.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
 7月 01 12:19:30 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
 7月 01 12:20:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Created slice user-0.slice.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
 7月 01 12:20:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Session 10 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-10.scope has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-10.scope has begun starting up.
 7月 01 12:20:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Session 10 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-10.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit session-10.scope has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
 7月 01 12:20:01 localhost.localdomain CROND[6983]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
```

でした。情報が少ないので苦戦しています。

---

```
# mysqladmin ping
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

---

> /var/lib/mysql/ホスト名.err ファイルに何かエラーの原因が記録されているかもしれません。
>
> また、mysql-libs は CentOS 7.1 にはありません。mariadb-libs (5.5.41) でしょうか？
> mysql.com など別のリポジトリのものでしょうか？
> CentOS 7.1 の mariadb-libs であれば、MariaDB-shared がインストールされるときに置き換わるので、手動でアンインストールする必要はないはず。

```
 # cat localhost.localdomain.err
150703 09:46:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150703  9:46:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.0.20-MariaDB) starting as process 8775 ...
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150703  9:46:47 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150703  9:46:47 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150703  9:46:47 [ERROR] Aborting

150703  9:46:47 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150703 09:46:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid ended
```

`./ibdata1`の書き込みができないっぽいので所有者/所有グループを変えてみました。

```
# cd /var/lib/mysql
# ls -l
合計 110644
-rw-rw----. 1 root  root    16384  7月  1 11:44 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----. 1 root  root       52  7月  1 11:44 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----. 1 root  root 50331648  7月  1 11:44 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 root  root 50331648  7月  1 11:44 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw----. 1 root  root 12582912  7月  1 11:44 ibdata1
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql root    22584  7月  3 09:46 localhost.localdomain.err
drwx------. 2 root  root     4096  7月  1 11:44 mysql
drwx------. 2 root  root     4096  7月  1 11:44 performance_schema
drwx------. 2 root  root        6  7月  1 11:44 test

# cd ../
# chown mysql:mysql mysql -R
```

これで`systemctl start mysql`を実行したところ、うまくいきました！

```
# systemctl start mysql
# systemctl status mysql
mysql.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql)
   Active: active (running) since 金 2015-07-03 09:50:42 JST; 12s ago
  Process: 20024 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─20029 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/...
           └─20102 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-...

 7月 03 09:50:40 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MyS....
 7月 03 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain mysql[20024]: Starting MySQL. SUCCESS!
 7月 03 09:50:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop MySQL.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

mariaDBの起動後は`mysql.sock`ができました

```
# ls -l
合計 110648
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql    16384  7月  1 11:44 aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql       52  7月  1 11:44 aria_log_control
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 50331648  7月  3 09:50 ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 50331648  7月  1 11:44 ib_logfile1
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql 12582912  7月  3 09:50 ibdata1
-rw-r-----. 1 mysql mysql    24010  7月  3 09:50 localhost.localdomain.err
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        6  7月  3 09:50 localhost.localdomain.pid
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql        0  7月  3 09:50 multi-master.info
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql     4096  7月  1 11:44 mysql
srwxrwxrwx. 1 mysql mysql        0  7月  3 09:50 mysql.sock
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql     4096  7月  1 11:44 performance_schema
drwx------. 2 mysql mysql        6  7月  1 11:44 test
```

起動の確認

```
# mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3
Server version: 10.0.20-MariaDB MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

mysql-libsはmysql.comのものです。
mariaDBをインストールする前にやったことを簡単にご説明いたしますと、以前MySQLをインストールしました。しかし起動に`error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")'`とのエラーが出て、解決できずに放置しておりました。それでとりあえずmariaDBに移行してみようと思ったのです。ちなみにこのCentOS7.1はVirtualBoxで動かしてるものです。

Comment: コメント欄と回答を間違って書いてました…。/etc/init.d/mysql の中で、mysqladmin ping を実行して応答があれば SUCESS、なければ ERROR となっていると思います。mysqladmin ping が何かしらエラーを出力している可能性があるので mysqladmin ping の結果を調べて教えてください。具体的には、「wait_for_ready()」関数のなかの。「if $bindir/mysqladmin ping >/dev/null 2>&1; then」という記述を探して、「>/dev/null 2>&1」を削除してください。また、「elif kill -o $! >/dev/null 2>&1; then」という記述を探して、同じように消してください。その上で、/etc/init.d/mysql start を実行するとエラーメッセージが表示されるはずです。

Answer (score 1):

あいにくファイル現物が手元にないので、ここだ、というのは特定できませんが

systemctl status mysqlの出力によれば/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqlをExecStartしたときのプロセスidは6341で、そのプロセス6341は

```
7月 01 12:12:03 localhost.localdomain mysql[6341]: Starting MySQL. ERROR!
```

と言って止まっているので、/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqlの中でERROR!というメッセージを出す判定をしているところを見つければ原因もわかると思います。

Answer (score 1):

/var/lib/mysql/ホスト名.err ファイルに何かエラーの原因が記録されているかもしれません。

また、mysql-libs は CentOS 7.1 にはありません。mariadb-libs (5.5.41) でしょうか？
mysql.com など別のリポジトリのものでしょうか？
CentOS 7.1 の mariadb-libs であれば、MariaDB-shared がインストールされるときに置き換わるので、手動でアンインストールする必要はないはず。

念のため、RPM が正しくインストールされているか、ファイルに破損がないか調べるといいと思います。

```
# rpm -qa "MariaDB*"
MariaDB-shared-10.0.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-common-10.0.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-server-10.0.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-client-10.0.20-1.el7.centos.x86_64

# rpm -Va "MariaDB*"
  (修正した設定ファイル以外、出力されない)
```

Comment: パーミッションの問題だったようです。ご確認ください。

Comment: 変更後のパーミッションで問題ないと思います。